# Sharepoint 2013 Calendar Events and layout

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I have a couple of questions regarding sharepoint 2013 calendar

1, How can i change the layout of my default sharepoint calendar (apply styles and change its size), or is there any free web part available for this purpose?

2, I want to change the Cell click event on sharepoint 2013 default calendar, rite now its redirecting on calendar control maximized view. how can i change that link so i cant redirect it on some perticular page.

I am newb in sharepoint2013 so please reply as simple as possible :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article about how to style SP calendar to make it small and use it for the Intranet

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2013/04/small-calendar-for-sharepoint-2010-2013.html

Here is the 3rd party nice component which we considered but it is kind of expensive

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-mini-calendar-web-part.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, i have already tried This link, how ever it has not explained it very well but it worked for me :) Thanks Any way

Comment: any help on the same